# Mod_Rewrite: How to rewrite just the main domain, not any other folders/files?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Here's the issue: I have quite a long htaccess, doing a lot of redirects (it's a store site, and it's redirecting things like STOREID/p/PRODUCTID to productdetail.php?s=STOREID&p=PRODUCTID, etc. I want the ability to allow specific stores to have direct domain names. So, you go to examplestore.com, it hits mysite.com/stores, and then htaccess rewrites it to mysite.com/stores/STOREID. I've got this working except for one thing:

I can get the main page to come up, or the product/search/etc pages to come up, but not both.

Here's the relevant part of my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^(www\.)?EXAMPLESTOREDOMAIN\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule /?$ /6804/  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /6804/$1    [QSA]
```

Later on in the htaccess it works on things like /p/ and whatnot, and all of that works great. The 6804 is the store id, and htaccess later grabs this and dumps it out to php as a url variable.

I can remove the first rule, and then everything else works. Or I can have the first rule, and nothing else works. It doesn't matter the order of the rules, either.

Here's what should happen:
http://EXAMPLESTOREDOMAIN.com --> mystore.com/stores/6804/ --> mystore.com/stores/storeindex.php?s=6804
http://EXAMPLESTOREDOMAIN.com/p/22/ --> mystore.com/stores/6804/p/22 --> mystore.com/stores/productdetail.php?s=6804&p=22

The second rewrite step works great. The first, not so much. And I'd set it up with each of the second rules to work on each domain individually, but I don't want to do that and have that large of an htaccess if we get to having a few hundred store domains...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the first condition to also apply to the second rule, as it is, it's only affecting the first one. That's why when you remove the first rule, the second one works. The RewriteCond's only apply the first RewriteRule that's after them. The `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^(www\.)?EXAMPLESTOREDOMAIN\.com$ [NC]` just needs to be copied and placed above the second RewriteRule.

Comment: This was necessary, but also it turns out I missed a ^ on the first rewrite rule. Once I did these two things, it works. Thanks!